# Confused with 64bit and 32 bit when using JNI

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I have a Java project running under windows. It uses several native functions from a .DLL file via JNI. Everything works well under 32bit windows.

In order to support 64bit windows, I need to deal with the following questions first:

1. Can I load a 32bit DLL under 32bit VM in 64bit windows?
2. Can I load a 32bit DLL under 64bit VM in 64bit windows?
3. Can I load a 64bit DLL under 32bit VM in 64bit windows?
4. How can I know which DLL file to load?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you're dealing with VMs. the guest OS will essentially have NO knowledge of what the host OS, nor really should it. If you're running a 32bit windows, then you cannot run 64bit software. Period. doesn't matter if the vm is hosted by a 64bit windows. the 32bit windows that's running your app will not have 64bit support.

Comment: I am concerned about the DLL, which calls the host OS APIs. Do you mean that I can just ignore the host OS and even a 32bit DLL is supported by a 64bit windows?

Comment: 64bit win has syswow64, which is the "32bit app-on-64bit OS" layer. you can call 32bit code from a 64bit app.

Answer (score 1):

A 64-bit OS can run a 32-bit or 64-bit application.

A 32-bit application can only load 32-bit DLL or shared libraries.

A 64-bit application can only load 64-bit DLL or shared libraries.